# Solution to avoid non-sargable argument in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

In the `code_list` CTE in this query I have a row constructor that will eventually take any number of arguments.  The column `icd` in the `patient_codes` CTE is a five digit identifier that is most descriptive that the three digit codes that the row constructor has.  The table `icd_patient` has a 100 million rows so for performance's sake, I would like to filer the rows on this table before I do any further work.  I have

```
;with code_list(code_list)
as
(
    select  x.code_list
      from (values ('70700'),('25002')) as x(code_list)
),patient_codes
as
(

select distinct  icd,pat_id,id
    from icd_patient
    where icd in (select icd from code_list)
)
select distinct pat_id from patient_codes
```

The problem is, however, is that in the icd_patient table all of the `icd` columns are five digit and more descriptive.  If I look at the execution plan of this query it's pretty streamlined.  If I do

```
;with code_list(code_list)
as
(
    select  x.code_list
      from (values ('70700'),('25002')) as x(code_list)
),patient_codes
as
(
    select substring(icd,1,3) as icd,pat_id
      from icd_patient2
      where substring(icd,1,3) in (select * from code_list)
)
select * from patient_codes
```

this if course has a large performance impact because of the substring expression in the where clause.  Does something akin to `like in` exist so I can take advantage of my indexes?

Index on icd_patient
`CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_icd_patient] ON [dbo].[icd_patient2] 
(
    [pat_id] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [id],`

Comment: Where did you pick up this habit of using `IN (SELECT *`?

Comment: My brain told me is was a good idea.  I'm going to assume that is isn't?

Comment: You should name the column you're referring to. `IN (SELECT *` happens to work because your table only has one column, but this is not typical and makes the code horribly misleading IMHO.

Comment: I would agree with that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This much simpler query should be better than (or, at worst, the same as) your existing query.

```
select pat_id
    FROM dbo.icd_patient
    where icd LIKE '707%'
       OR icd LIKE '250%'
GROUP BY pat_id;
```

Note that sargability only matters if there is actually an index on this column.

An alternative (since `OR` can sometimes give the optimizer fits):

```
SELECT pat_id FROM 
(
  SELECT pat_id
    FROM dbo.icd_patient
    WHERE icd LIKE '707%'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT pat_id
    FROM dbo.icd_patient
    WHERE icd LIKE '250%'
) AS x
GROUP BY pat_id;
```

To make this extensible beyond a handful of OR conditions, I would use a table-valued parameter (TVP).

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.StringPatterns AS TABLE(s VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then your stored procedure could say:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
  @sp dbo.StringPatterns READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT p.pat_id
    FROM dbo.icd_patient AS p
    INNER JOIN @sp AS sp
    ON p.pat_id LIKE sp.s + '%'
  GROUP BY p.pat_id;
END
```

Then you can pass in your set of three-character substrings from a `DataTable` or other collection in C#. From T-SQL just as an example:

```
DECLARE @p dbo.StringPatterns;
INSERT @p VALUES('707'),('250');
EXEC dbo.whatever @sp = @p;
```

Comment: Yes there's an index CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [icd_patient2] ON [dbo].[icd_patient] 
(
 [icd] ASC
).  That query gives me a plan of http://imgur.com/wdROtbi

Comment: @wootscootinboogie yep sorry missed that. So seems like it was able to use an index seek.

Comment: If I wanted to make this extensible so the row constructor could grow as large as needed, what would you recommend?  Obviously a bunch of ORs wouldn't do.  Do you think that would be a candidate for full-text indexing?  I'm pretty ignorant about it, but I know it exists.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . the optimizer recognizes `p.pat_id LIKE sp.s + '%'` for sargability?  Cool.

Answer (score 2):

Something like `like in` does not exist.  The following is sargable:

```
select *
from icd_patient
where icd like '70700%' or
      icd like '25002%'
```

Because `like` with a constant initial substring is a special case for SQL Server.  This does not work when the strings on the right are variables.

One solution is to create an indexed view on the `icd_patient` table with an index on the first five characters of the icd code.

Comment: Indexed view? That's an odd suggestion. I would think an indexed computed column would make more sense than a completely separate object.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . That is a really good suggestion.  I had just thought of the view first.

Comment: Also this query will return duplicates (and I think the part about only caring about the first three characters was missed). But even still, I'm not sure what an index on the first few characters would offer that an index on the column itself wouldn't... if the wildcard were reversed then you'd have to take the last n characters.

Answer (score 2):

Using "IN" makes that part of a command non-sargable on both sides. End of discussion.

Saying he fixes it using substring, completely changes what it would return while it remains non sarged.

Any "fix" should exactly match results. The actual fix is to join the cte so the five characters match or put three characters in the cte and match that in a join or put 4 characters in the cte where the fourth is "%" and join matching by using LIKE

Using a "like" that starts with "%" increases the complexity of the search, but it would still use the index to find the value because parsing the index should use less reading by only getting the full table row when a search is successful.